# How to compare the elements of linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

May someone please explain me why loop is iterated only 3 times?

```
#include <iostream> using namespace std;

struct Node{
    Node *link;
    float x; };

Node *head = NULL;

int main() {   Node *first = new Node();   first -> x = 2.0;   first
-> link = NULL;   head = first;

  Node *second = new Node();   first -> link = second;   second -> x =
1.4;   second -> link = NULL;

  Node *third = new Node();   second -> link = third;   third -> x =
3.4;   third -> link = NULL;

////////////////////////////Delete   /*Node *delfirst = head;   head = head->link;*/   Node *a = head;   Node *b = head;
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        a = a -> link;

    }
    b = b -> link;   } return 0; }
```

Comment: it's iterated only 3 times because this codes  creates only 3 nodes inside your list

Comment: then how may I compare like "first and second elements" then "first and third elements" and then "second and third elements"  and so on?

Comment: Can you explain me why this code has such a terrible formatting?

Comment: It is just example.I am learning the linked list.Actually I know that to use "for" here is not right way.

Comment: what loop? there are two and both have exactly 3 iterations...

Comment: You have literally set the loop to run exactly 3 times with the i < 3.

Comment: MY question like if i will have array instead of Linked list then with this code I may compare the elements with all other elements.But here it does not do it and I do not know how may write it

Comment: it actually does exactly like you would do in the array case you have a loop inside a loop so for each element you are comparing it with the content of the whole list

Comment: how may I do it with linked list?

Answer (score 0):

The code would look like this

```
Node * a=head;
while(a->link)
{
 Node * b=a->link;
 while(b)
 {
  if(a->x == b->x)
   dosomething();
  b=b->link;
 }
a=a->link
}
```

Comment: exactly.Thanks a lot